# How to change the initial go pagination October CMS

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, octobercms

I have a problem on the October CMS (Laravel). How to change the starting number id? For example, when I put 6 elements on each page, pagination on my first path there are 2 elements on the remaining 6. How to be Help please? How to change the initial go pagination October cms.Thanks.My code:

```
{% set records = PasopList.records %}
{% set displayColumn = PasopList.displayColumn %}
{% set noRecordsMessage = PasopList.noRecordsMessage %}
{% set detailsPage = PasopList.detailsPage %}
{% set detailsKeyColumn = PasopList.detailsKeyColumn %}
{% set detailsUrlParameter = PasopList.detailsUrlParameter %}

<div class="tpl-block-list tpl-component-183 tpl-template-229" id="nc-block-0d376408f9ff3d4eb20309cde237bb59">
 <div class = "container container-mb-4">
<article class="company">
   {%for record in records%}
     {% spaceless %}
     {%set k=k+1%}
     {%if k%2==1 %}
       <div class="row" style = "padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;">
                 <div class = "col-md-6">
                   <img src = "{{record.image.path}}" style = "width:100%;">
                 </div>
              <div class = "col-md-6"  style = "paddinig-bottom:12px;margin:auto;">
                    <p>{{record.text_ru|raw}}</p>
              </div>        
        </div>
     {%elseif k%2==0 %}
        <div class="row" style = "padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;">
          <div class = "col-md-6"  style = "paddinig-bottom:12px;margin:auto;">
            <p>{{record.text_ru|raw}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class = "col-md-6">
             <img src = "{{record.image.path}}" style = "width:100%;"> 
          </div>        
        </div>
     {%endif%}

       {% endspaceless %}
 {%endfor%}
</article>
```

My pagination code:

```
   <div class="pagination-block w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
 {% if records.lastPage >1 %}
  <ul class="pagination custom-pag">
    {% if records.currentPage > 1 %}
    <li class="page-item custom-pag-item">
      <a class="page-link custom-pag-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (records.currentPage-1) }) }}" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
   {% endif %}
    {% for page in 1..records.lastPage %}
    <li class="page-item custom-pag-item">
        <a class="page-link custom-pag-link {{ records.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- <li class="page-item custom-pag-item"><a class="page-link custom-pag-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item custom-pag-item"><a class="page-link custom-pag-link" href="#">3</a></li> -->

    {% if records.lastPage > records.currentPage %}
    <li class="page-item custom-pag-item">
      <a class="page-link custom-pag-link" href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (records.currentPage+1) }) }}" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>  
  {%endif%}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your pagination code? PHP and Twig HTML

Comment: Yes, I can, but I solved the problem in a different way, I just used to have 2 lists stored in one table, divided them into different tables and models. But it’s interesting to do without dividing? See my edited my question

Comment: So I guess I should have asked for a screenshot of what you are getting and what you want to achieve. I am not quite sure what you are asking.